# sum the every n number of row values in pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a data like this .

```
 1:23:0.20
 2:34:0.50
 3:67:0.90
 4:87:0.10
 5:23:0.12
```

I am trying to sum the every 2 rows last column values like this.

```
0.20+0.50 = 0.70
0.90+0.10 = 1.0
```

and print like this

```
 1:23:0.20:0.70
 2:34:0.50:0.70
 3:67:0.90:1.0
 4:87:0.10:1.0
 5:23:0.12
```

This is my pig script

```
 data = LOAD '/home/user/Documents/test/test.txt' using PigStorage(':') AS (tag:int,rssi:chararray,weightage:chararray,seqnum:int);
B = FOREACH (GROUP data ALL) {
A_ordered = ORDER data BY rssi;
GENERATE FLATTEN(CUSTOM_UDF(A_ordered));
}
```

I tried with java UDF. but not works properly.

```
this is what I tried.

public List<String> sumValues() {
    List<String> processedList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (entries == null) {
        return processedList;
    } else {
        double columnSum = 0;
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        int length = entries.size();
        for (int index = 1; index <= length; index++) {
            tempList.add(entries.get(index - 1)); 
            String[] splitValues = entries.get(index - 1).split(DELIMITER);
            if (splitValues.length >= MIN_SPLIT_STRING_LENGTH) {

                try {
                    double lastValue = Double.parseDouble(splitValues[WEIGHTAGE_INDEX]);
                    columnSum = columnSum + lastValue;

                    if ((index % ROWS_TO_BE_SUMMED == 0) || (index == length)) {
                        for (String tempString : tempList) {
                            processedList.add(tempString + ":" + columnSum);
                        }
                        tempList.clear(); // Clear the temporary array
                        columnSum = 0;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid weightage");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
    return processedList;
}


@Override
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("------INSIDE EXEC FUCTION ----" + input);
    if (input != null && input.size() != 0) {
        try {
            String str = (String) input.get(0);
            if (str != null) {
                String splitStrings[] = str.split(":");
                if (splitStrings != null && splitStrings.length >= 3 && splitStrings[2].equals(EXIT)) {
                    List<String> processedList = sumValues();
                    String sum = processedList.toString();
                    System.out.println("SUM VALUE----:" + sum);
                    return sum;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("INPUT VALUE----:" + str);
                    entries.add(str);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

The above code prints empty results.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in PIG itself.Generate another column say f11 based on even rows in your dataset and subtract 1 from it to create sets of 2 rows with same id.This will allow you to group those two records on the new column and sum the final column.Then join the new set with the relation and get the desired columns.

Note: For n rows sum,use f1%n_value.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(':') AS (f1:int,f2:int,f3:double);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,(f1%2 == 0 ? (f1-1):f1) AS f11,f2,f3;
C = GROUP B BY f11;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group AS f11,SUM(f3) AS Total;
E = JOIN B BY f11,D BY f11;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE B.f1,B.f2,B.f3,D.Total;-- Note:use B::f1,B::f2,B::f3,D::Total if '.' doesn't work.
```

**Output**

**A**

```
1,23,0.20
2,34,0.50
3,67,0.90
4,87,0.10
5,23,0.12
```

**B** - Add a new second column based on even row number - 1.

```
1,1,23,0.20
2,1,34,0.50
3,3,67,0.90
4,3,87,0.10
5,5,23,0.12
```

**C** - Group by the new second column

```
1,{(1,23,0.20),(2,34,0.50)}
3,{(3,67,0.90),(4,87,0.10)}
5,{(5,23,0.12)}
```

**D** - Generate the sum after grouping

```
1,0.70
3,1.0
5,0.12
```

**E** - Join the dataset from previous step with B using the new column

```
1,1,23,0.20,1,0.70
2,1,34,0.50,1,0.70
3,3,67,0.90,3,1.0
4,3,87,0.10,3,1.0
5,5,23,0.12,5,0.12
```

**E** - Get the desired columns.

```
1,23,0.20,0.70
2,34,0.50,0.70
3,67,0.90,1.0
4,87,0.10,1.0
5,23,0.12,0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

In your udf you recieve `tuple(int, chararray, chararray, int)` and try to obtain first element as `String`. As you surrounded code with `try...catch` you don't see `ClassCastException` that definitely occurs there. Aso you don't need to split value by `:` as you've already loaded it split.

Comment: Nope its printing empty results only